# SQL query to get disctinct count of id and distinct count of sub item id

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table like this:

```
item_id   sub_item_id
=======   ===========
1         11
1         12
1         13
2         21
2         21 -- repeat
2         22
2         23
2         24
2         25
3         31
3         31 -- repeat
```

Is it possible to write a query that outputs 2 counts: The count of distinct item_ids and a count of distinct sub_item_ids across all item_ids. In summary, if that query is run against the sample data above, it would produce `3, 9` as output.

I can certainly do this like below but it will produce a verbose output and I will have to then run that data through a spreadsheet to get distinct count of item_ids:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(sub_item_id))
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: `select count(distinct a), count(distinct a, b) from t` ?

Comment: select count(distinct item_id), count(distinct sub_item_id) from t

Comment: @ValNik - believe me I tried to apply that thought before posting the question but definitely I missed something. This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example, pointed in my comment

```
select count(distinct item_id) item_qty
   ,count(distinct sub_item_id) sub_item_qty
from my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put two `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` calls in the SELECT list.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) AS distinct_item_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT sub_item_id) AS distinct_sub_item_count
FROM my_table
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Uq3ej1vEUvBRf5tBxLsYW/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the distinct combinations of item_id and sub_item_id. Then, the outer query counts the distinct item_id and the distinct sub_item_id across all the results.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) AS distinct_item_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT sub_item_id) AS distinct_sub_item_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT item_id, sub_item_id
  FROM my_table
) AS distinct_items;
```